# How create Azure Front domains with pre-validated domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door, azure-waf

I'm trying to validate FrontDoor custom domains using the [Azure pre-validated domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-add-custom-domain#:%7E:text=Azure%20pre%2Dvalidated%20domain%20is%20a%20domain%20already%20validated%20by%20another%20Azure%20service.%20When%20you%20select%20this%20option%2C%20domain%20ownership%20validation%20isn%27t%20required%20from%20Azure%20Front%20Door.%20A%20dropdown%20list%20of%20validated%20domains%20by%20different%20Azure%20services%20appear.).

I have web app origins that already validated their custom domains, and I wan't to be able to import them to the front door instance without the need to revalidate all of them with txt records.

But unfortunately I can't. The drop down show nothing :

[image]

I'm using Premium FrontDoor, and created the oring groups with the web apps.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Currently Azure pre-validated domains only supports domains validated by Static Web App.

Comment: Refer here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-add-custom-domain#add-a-new-custom-domain

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by SiddheshDesai in comment, FrontDoot supports importing validated domain only from Static Web App...

Thanks !